# Use python itertools to loop over two database tables in Django

Tags: python, django, python-itertools

I am building a project in Django. It's like a blog page where a user can post journals and photos. I am trying to make a page where everything the person posted is displayed in chronological order. My simplified models.py is shown below.

```
class Writing(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)

class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
```

In this case, I would have to touch two database tables, and then order them by date_created. I heard that I can use itertools chain to loop through these two tables, but I am not sure exactly how. What should I write in views.py?

Comment: Read [Writing your first Django app, part 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Combining two querysets isn't covered by the tutorials, so linking to the docs isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple in the views.py you can for example:

```
def my_view(request):
    writing = Writing.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-date_created')
    photos = Photo.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-date_created')
    context = {'writing': writing, 'photos': photos}
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', context)
```

One more hint you shouldn't use BigIntegerField for date, instead of it use DateTime

```
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```